# Issue with finding row ID in a data table in R

Tags: r, rowid

I have a data frame like below. How can I get the row id when all elements are present in a data table.

For example,

```
Table:

    L001 044 N   004 E   036 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
    L001 086 N   016 E   016 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
    L001 092 N   011 E   026 L002 044 N   006 E   022
    L001 056 N   036 E   061 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I need to obtain the row id in "Table" when all elements are filled. For example in this example row id is 3 since all columns in "Table" has a value.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is this table stored? A text file? Relational database?

Comment: its a data table reading from a text file.

Comment: Then you need to read it line by line anyway, so you can just count the line number and test every line. If all the fields are set, return / exit with the current line number.

Comment: `which(rowSums(is.na(df)) == 0)`

Comment: Please, NUdu, unambiguous data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53672753/issue-with-pasting-5-columns-groups-in-r/53672956#comment94203877_53672753

Answer (score 0):

Where `df` equals:

```
df = read.table(
  text = "
  L001 044 N   004 E   036 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
  L001 086 N   016 E   016 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
  L001 092 N   011 E   026 L002 044 N   006 E   022
  L001 056 N   036 E   061 NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
  "
)
```

You can do:

```
rownames(df[complete.cases(df)==TRUE,])
```

Resulting in:

```
[1] "3"
```